# Merge many queries into one query to speed up

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have written a procedure that collects data from 4 tables and issues a general report for the day.

There are two similar SQL queries in the procedure, the execution time of each of which is more than 1 seconds, respectively, the procedure execution time is more than 2 seconds, can this be optimized?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE cv
    @dt AS SMALLDATETIME
AS
    SELECT
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0)
         FROM RCassa 
         WHERE DataRC = @dt) AS crMagPDP,
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SumPrice), 0) - 
                    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0)
         FROM RCassa 
         WHERE DataRC = @dt) AS crMag,
for browse
```

2 queries are shown just as an example, there are more subqueries.

Whole procedure:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CV
    @dt as SMALLDATETIME
AS

SELECT
    (SELECT isnull(sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0)
        FROM RCassa WHERE DataRC = @dt) as crMagPDP,
    (SELECT ISNULL(sum(SumPrice), 0) - isnull(sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0)
        FROM RCassa WHERE DataRC = @dt) AS crMag,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.Price_Sp), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Sp >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Out_Date)) = @dt
    ) as crParts,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.Price_Total - ISNULL(What_Done.Price_Diag, 0)), 0)
      FROM What_Done INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE  What_Done.Price_Total > 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Out_Date)) = @dt
      ) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.Price_Diag), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Total >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Order_Date)) = @dt
    ) as crCassa,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.Price_Diag), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Total >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0 AND What_Done.BCard_IN <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Order_Date)) = @dt
      ) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.Price_Total - ISNULL(What_Done.Price_Diag, 0)), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Total >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0 AND What_Done.BCard_OUT <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Out_Date)) = @dt
    ) as crBCard,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summ), 0) FROM RevOrd WHERE Summ >= 0 AND Nal <> 0 AND DateOrd = @dt) as crNal,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summ), 0) FROM RevOrd WHERE Summ >= 0 AND Nal = 0 AND DateOrd = @dt) as crCard,
    (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(SumTotal), 0) FROM LineOrders WHERE DataOut = @dt) as crLine,
    (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(SumTotal), 0) FROM LineOrders WHERE DataOut = @dt and Dost <> 0) as crDostavka,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.BCard_IN_Sum), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Total >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0 AND What_Done.BCard_IN <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Order_Date)) = @dt
      )+(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(What_Done.BCard_OUT_Sum), 0)
      FROM What_Done
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON What_Done.uid = ORDERS.uid
      WHERE What_Done.Price_Total >= 0 AND What_Done.Nal <> 0 AND What_Done.BCard_OUT <> 0
      AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(12), ORDERS.Out_Date)) = @dt
    ) as crBCardCorrect
for browse
```

Comment: How many records are there in RCassa?  Are your indexes solid?

Comment: @DestroyNet . . . Something seems wrong with your question.  You mention four tables but the query only references one.  The logic of subtracting `SUM(price * kvo)` from `SUM(price)` is also suspicious.  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Comment: Make sure there's an index on DataRC

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, the remaining queries to the other tables are similar to these 2 queries, there was no point in placing the whole procedure, it would be superfluous.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, although ... I think you're still right, the first message has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the criteria for the sub-queries are identical and filter on `DataRC = @dt` and use the same data source `RCassa`, then you can simplify the query like this:

```
SELECT
  isnull(sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0) as crMagPDP,
  ISNULL(sum(SumPrice), 0) - isnull(sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Price * Kvo END), 0) AS crMag,
  ...
FROM RCassa
WHERE DataRC = @dt
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried ... and got an error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @DestroyNet How many rows are you returning?  For complex reporting queries like this, it can be useful to build up a temp #Table with the results.  The stored procedure can gather up selected rows into the temp #Table, set other columns from other tables, and then return the results.  This works fine for most reports we write, but if you are returning a lot of data (many millions of rows, for example), the I/O burden of moving these rows around can be very slow.

Comment: This procedure returns a single row, which after additional processing is saved to another table.

Answer (score 0):

If the outer `select` is from other table[s] use APPLY

```
SELECT
    isnull(t.crMagPDP, 0) crMagPDP,
    isnull(t.crMag, 0) crMag,
    ..
 FROM 
 ..
 OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Price * Kvo END) as crMagPDP,
      sum(SumPrice) - sum(CASE WHEN PrePayDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Price * Kvo END) AS crMag,
      ...
    FROM RCassa
    WHERE DataRC = @dt
  ) t
```